# Как распарсить функцию?

Tags: java, android

Как достать `href`, с помощью языка `Java`?

Как написать данную обработку?

```
function PrepareMarkers() {
    points = [];
    points[0] = {
      'TEXT': '<div class=\'wc_overview\' align=\'left\'><h3 align=\'left\'><a href=\"/cams/web-camera-adler-online/the-intersection-of-lenin-and-kirov/\">Перекресток улиц Ленина и Кирова. Адлер веб камера онлайн<\/a><\/h3>Веб-камера осуществляет трансляцию с перекрестка улиц Ленина и Кирова в Адл…<\/div>',
      'LON': '39.92437005043',
      'LAT': '43.42605043029',
      'MARK': '/03_A.png'
    };
    points[1] = {
      'TEXT': '<div class=\'wc_overview\' align=\'left\'><h3 align=\'left\'><a href=\"/cams/web-camera-adler-online/adler-market-ring/\">Рыночное кольцо. Адлер веб камера онлайн<\/a><\/h3>Данная веб-амера расположена на здании бизнес-центра &quot;ВиЛа&quot;, кото…<\/div>',
      'LON': '39.926311969757',
      'LAT': '43.425606287619',
      'MARK': '/03_A.png'
    };
    points[2] = {
      'TEXT': '<div class=\'wc_overview\' align=\'left\'><h3 align=\'left\'><a href=\"/cams/web-camera-adler-online/adler-ring/\">Адлерское кольцо. Адлер веб камера онлайн<\/a><\/h3>Веб-камера демонстрирует дорожную развязку &quot;Адлерское кольцо, на перек…<\/div>',
      'LON': '39.920539855957',
      'LAT': '43.441235032114',
      'MARK': '/03_A.png'
    };
```

Comment: [Обработка строк в Java. Часть II: Pattern, Matcher](https://habrahabr.ru/post/260773/)

Answer (score 0):

Пусть `s` – исходный текст (`JS`-код), тогда:

С помощью регулярных выражений:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a href=\\\\\"([a-z\\/-]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```